# Delphi Seattle - Locking Query problems

Tags: delphi, locking, firebird, delphi-10-seattle, firedac

I'm trying to implement the *pessimistic lock* on my application and follow tutorials on Firedac explaining how to proceed. In my query I am informing `Lock Mode lmPessimistic` and `Lock Point lpImmediate`.
The lock works perfectly, not allowing me to access this record from another application instance. But it causes me a problem with transactions I do not know to solve, because never have explicitly worked with them.

Example:

- I enter the screen using Edit;
- Change the values;
  I have to use a ApplyUpdates (0) CommitUpdates and Edit in the Query, because it is a master-detail;
- Finally I record everything and close the screen.

Works perfectly, I refresh the record in my other open application and values ​​are updated. But if I do the same test again, when I close the screen, the values ​​are not updated in my second application. They are only updated when I close the first application.

I have found that what is causing it is the `Query.Edit` in the process. I think it's a problem with transactions, but did not put any type of component in the project, I know firedac is responsible for creating them for me. But I will have to set up anything else?

P.S.: I'm using `CachedUpdates = True`

Comment: Sounds like you are not committing the current transaction, and firedac commits for you when the application closes. Find out how you can commit in firedac.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I discovered that the problem is CachedUpdates = True. If I turn off the lock and transactions work properly.